# Missing column headers on a custom search

Tags: custom-search

CiviCRM 5.6.1
Drupal: 7.59

I have a problem with my custom search outside of core, but i was able to replicate issue on "Proximity Search" which comes in core.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to Proximity search http://example.com/civicrm/contact/search/custom?reset=1&csid=6
2. Modify its file "civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Custom/Proximity.php"
3. Edit buildform function to add "$form->set('component_mode', 16); //Events mode", in the very end of function right after $form->assign
4. Run search
5. You will notice column headers should be missing, after adding component mode, search disregards columns headers which were set using $this->_columns